# How long does it take to get an Indian visa in London for a UK national?

Tags: visas, india, london, uk-citizens

I am running a bit late with my visa application to India, as I am still waiting for my passport... How long does it take to get a double-entry tourist visa in London's office for a UK national? Is there a way to speed up this process? Is it slower for a person with different passport, but resident in the UK?

EDIT: I can apply and collect my passport personally.

Comment: Are you planning to go yourself, or use an agency?

Comment: FWIW, using an agency, I got my passport back with business visa in under a week, with it having to be posted both ways, on the 2nd quickest processing option the agency did

Comment: @Gagravarr, I don't know. I would like to use the fastest possible service basically...

Answer (score 4):

It's often said that getting an Indian visa is good preparation for your visit, as the confusing and often chaotic process is a good introduction to your time there... I think there's at least something to be said for that!

You would think that the place to look would be the [Indian High Commission in London website](http://hcilondon.in/), but that doesn't seem to contain the sorts of info you're probably used to finding. As best as I can tell, you need to [apply online via a third party](http://in.vfsglobal.co.uk/index.html), then either post off your application, or deliver it to them in person. The website for that has all the links you'd expect, but doesn't always have the info you want on them!

Alternately, there are a number of agencies who'll handle it for you for an additional fee. Several of them offer a 3 day service for tourist visas, and quicker for business visas. There's possibly quite a bit to be said for paying one of those companies to sort it out for you...

Comment: How can I find out which agencies are most trustworthy?

Comment: Ask around, check recommendations etc. Work normally use [India Visa 24](http://uk.travelvisa24.com/), and they seemed pretty good when they did mine

Answer (score 4):

OK, I have been there and got my visa. I decided to use the standard route, so to apply via [the appointed company](http://in.vfsglobal.co.uk/). The application is basically the same as in the agencies. It was easy to book an appointment for a convenient time for me. Then it took merely 3 days to get my passport back. No hassle anywhere. Seriously I can see no point to overpay and use the agencies.

Answer (score 2):

Having carefully completed on-line form, obtained photos in right format (did it myself but quite difficult), and double checked everything I sent it Royal Mail Special Delivery on 13 August 2014. Received back today 21 August 2014.

Don't know if this is typical - have done it before which means they can refer back to previous visa number - but why pay an agency to check everything or travel round the country to save postage unless you live close to where it can be handed in.

Photos are tricky though - suggest you start by taking photo landscape with chest included and at least half a head length above the top of the head. You then may need something like Photoshop elements to make sure you end up with the right size and proportions. Alternatively download to one of the advertised sites and they will do it for you.